# Не могу понять почему revOddWord("Dear Santa, give me a new iPhone") не работает коректно

Tags: javascript

Есть строка, переверните все слова нечетной длины. Слова четной длины не изменяются.
revOddWord("Egg") ➞ "ggE"
revOddWord ("It is false") ➞ "It is eslaf"
revOddWord ("Dear Santa, give me a new iPhone”)➞ "Dear atnaS, give me a wen iPhone. "

````
function revOddWord(str) {
    const punctuationMarks = [",", ".", "!", "?", ";", ":", "-",];
    const words = str.split(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length % 2 !== 0) {
            words[i] = words[i].split("").reverse().join("");
        }
        if (punctuationMarks.includes(words[i])) {
            str = words.slice(0, i) + words.slice(i + 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    return words.join(" ");
    return punctuationMarks.join(",");
}

console.log(revOddWord("Egg"));
console.log(revOddWord("It is false"));
console.log(revOddWord("Dear Santa, give me a new iPhone")); ```
````

Comment: Потому что ваш код считает, что в слове `Santa,` шесть букв (шестая буква — запятая)

Comment: @andreymal а как это пофиксить?

Comment: посмотрите на ответ от anton, на самом деле его ответ можно переписать в виде вашего цикла. как видите, у него слова разбивка идет по любому не словарному символу. у вас же по пробелам, да еще потом по разделителям (без сброса счетчика). что достаточно странно. я бы делал split по большему набору символов.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов мне бы по моему коду понять что делать, ибо с регуляркой не дружу :(

Comment: вот смотрите: у вас пробелы и разделители по разному обрабатываются. но их суть одна и та же: они должны остаться на месте. я бы сделал так: все небуквенные символы считал бы словами размером 1. разбивку по словам сделал бы в цикле (ибо split теряет разделитель). в следующем цикле перевернул бы слова нечетной длины и в конце соединил слова.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего использовать регулярное выражение:

```js
function revOddWord(str) {
  return str
    .replaceAll(/\w+/g, word => word.length % 2 !== 0
      ? word
        .split("")
        .reverse()
        .join("")
      : word);
}

console.log(revOddWord("Egg"));
console.log(revOddWord("It is false"));
console.log(revOddWord("Dear Santa, give me a new iPhone."));
// Вывод:
// ggE
// It is eslaf
// Dear atnaS, give me a wen iPhone.
```

```html
Ввод: <input id="target" oninput="document.getElementById('result').innerText = revOddWord(this.value); return true;"></input><br/>
Вывод: <a id="result"></a>
```

Comment: а если не регуляркой используя мой код, это сделать можно?